# Persist checkbox in gridview while custom paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a created a gridview and added a checkbox in item template. This grid has few columns along with `DataKey (primary key)`.  Due to performance gain, this grid will fetch the next set of recrods on each page change based on the page number click.  So that is done.

Now when user selects a checkbox in page one and then go to page 2 and coming back  to page one, then user will not see the checkbox checked as the user did earlier.

So is there a good way to persist the checkbox when user move page to page?

This checkbox be used as a flag to select the rows that can be deleted later by a button outside the grid.

Comment: What does the **checkbox** do ? Is it performing any kind of server operation on it's **oncheckedchanged** event like updating a single  or a set of field?

Comment: User would like to select the checkbox and then perform either delete  by clicking a button outside of the grid.  It is like functionality on the Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Since you receive a new set each time a paging is selected, I suggest the following approach:

Create an `array[]` object via javascript that will add to list the datakey whenever a checkbox is selected and in turn remove it if the checkbox is deselected. Something like this:

```
var selectedDataKeys = [];

$('.checkboxclass').on('change', function() {

   // Considering you assign the data key as id for the checkbox otherwise implement a way to retrieve the id.
   var dataKey = $(this).prop('id');

   // Determine if the dataKey is in the selected data keys array
   var isContained = (selectedDataKeys.indexOf(dataKey) > -1 );

   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      // If is contained is false - add to the array
      if (!isContained)
         selectedDataKeys.push(dataKey);
   } else {
      // If is contained is true - remove to the array
      if (isContained){
         selectedDataKeys = $.grep(selectedDataKeys, function(value) {
            return value != dataKey;
         });
      }
   }
});
```

From this point on the client user will have an active list of selected items, now its up to you to use that list to manipulate your grid display page. Either modify the display on document ready by comparing all the item on the grid display with the selectedDataKeys array or sending those keys and do the comparison server side.

Hope this helps.